# How to upload files to yammer using REST API?

Tags: yammer, yammer-api

I wanted an API to upload files to yammer.

Initially I was using https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/pending_attachments API which now gives DEPRECATED API response.

Then I moved to https://filesng.yammer.com/v4/uploadSmallFile API which was working earlier but now it gives 500 status code.

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

500 status code typically means you have the wrong authentication credentials or you don't have access, and the second API that you've listed requires AAD credentials. Once the correct AAD credentials are established, it should work.

Comment: 500 is *suppose* to be internal server error (something went wrong in the backend of the server).  A 401 code would be wrong authentication/invalid credentials.